# How did we shuffle the data and the labels?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, permutation, shuffle

Greetings software engineers, it is requested to help me. I am confused that how were the data and the labels shuffled in this code(the specific code i am referring to is in the 2nd picture)?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlaJj.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFwDS.png)

I am curious how are the data and the labels shuffled in this piece of code? I mean look what it's saying is basically(suppose we have 10 elements in data):

```
shuffle_indices = array([1, 7, 4, 3, 0, 9, 2, 5, 8, 6]) # random
data = data[array([1, 7, 4, 3, 0, 9, 2, 5, 8, 6])]
labels = labels[array([1, 7, 4, 3, 0, 9, 2, 5, 8, 6])]
```

Please explain how does this work?????

Comment: Please don't post code as an image. There are code blocks for that. [How to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) might also be helpful

Comment: You reorder (reindex) your `data` and `labels` arrays as defined by `shuffle_indices`, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

`random.permutation` produces a 'shuffled' List of numbers which can be used as indices into the array. This index List is then used to re-order the data. See basic example below and note how the changed data order follows the indices (remember Python is 0 index based so the first data element `a` is an index 0). The `seed` can be defined so the same shuffling order is produced each time.

```
import numpy as np

idx = np.random.permutation(5)

print(idx)

data = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
new_data = data[idx]
print(new_data)
```

shows:

```
[4 0 1 2 3]
['e' 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume shuffle_indices, data and labels are numpy arrays.

Numpy array can be indexed using another array. For example:

```
x = np.array([2, 1, 0])
y = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c'])
z = y[x]

print(z)  # ['c', 'b', 'a']
```

In this case, z is the reverse of y (a special case of shuffling).